# Focus on bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap dropdown, I want to focus on the dropdown so I can use keyboard to navigate over the list. What is the way to do it using jquery? 
I tried to use $('#myULid').focus() and this is not working.

I am able to open the dropdown, but not focus on it.

```
        <button id="time_btn" type="button"
                class="btn btn-reverse dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li ng-repeat="item in items" ><a><span>test</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your sourcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add

```
<ul  tabindex='1'>
....
</ul>
```

then add the .focus() method

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me, but for some reason when I select a list item and press ENTER it doesn't select the item.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent article "Accessible Dropdown Menus" all about the various ways to do this at http://terrillthompson.com/blog/202

It includes examples of various methods. One of the simplest can be seen at http://staff.washington.edu/tft/tests/menus/dropperdown/index.html. It is a pure CSS solution (no JavaScript) that was billed on it's invention as "the world's most accessible dropdown menu.".

However other more advanced methods are demoed as well. I hope it provides everything you need.